# How did operations on elliptic curves appear naturally in math history?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, math-history, elliptic-curves

I understand the basic operations on elliptic curves (e.g. points on $y^2 = x^3+7$, point at infinity, addition, multiplication, etc.).

I also see how it can be used for cryptography, based on the fact that given $G$ and $K=k*G$, it's very difficult to inverse the multiplication and recover $k$.

But here is the question:

How did mathematicians first get the idea of looking at the points on such curves $y^2 = a x^3+b$, and above all, **how did they get the idea of defining such an exotic addition?** (i.e. drawing a line from $P_1$ and $P_2$, then take the intersetion with the curve, **then reflect in the x-axis**, why this?).
*(I understand that with this definition, it allows to have an associative addition, and a group, but how did this appear?)*

How did this suddenly appear as an interesting math object to study, with such a non-obvious addition?

Comment: Franz Lemmermayer gave a nice answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156650/history-of-elliptic-curves); see also the references given there. Congruent numbers naturally lead to elliptic curves, too. Also, they appear as $1$-dimensional abelian varieties.

Comment: Intersecting curves is already a thing we do in algebraic geometry. In particular, intersecting with lines can be useful (we can parametrize rational points on circles and hyperbolas for instance, which yields an algorithm that produces all Pythagorean triples, as well as parametrize some other curves). Out of playing with intersecting elliptic curves with lines, they presumably noticed it always intersected in exactly three points (counting tangencies as double points and the point at infinity as one).

Comment: Nice answer indeed.  Here the question is more about the choice of the operation (especially addition which involves intersection and reflection),  do you have an idea about origin of this choice?

Comment: This all first came from the theory of elliptic functions, as studied by Abel, Jacobi et al.

Comment: @Basj: Franz Lemmermayer's answer linked to above seems to indicate that the group operation was known (in an analytic context, over $\mathbb{C}$) decades before it was described in these algebro-geometric terms.  So I would guess the algebro-geometric construction was reverse-engineered from what was already known about how the group structure on a torus relates to its algebraic structure via elliptic functions.

Comment: In other words, people didn't discover the group operation by just messing around with these geometric operations.  Instead, they started with complex tori, which have an obvious group operation, then discovered that complex tori can be embedded in $\mathbb{P}^2$ as the solution sets of cubic equations, and then figured out how to describe the group structure they already knew about in terms of the geometry of $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Answer (score 4):

The first constructions of points on curves of genus 1 can be found in the work of Diophantus, who taught how to find new rational solutions to certain equations by what much later was identified as the tangent method. Diophantus used clever (mainly linear) substitutions instead, as did Bachet, Fermat, Viete and Euler. Jacobi saw the connection between Euler's formulas and the theory of elliptic functions. The geometric interpretation of the linear substitutions as lines and the language of curves was first used by Sylvester, Lucas and Cayley.
For more, see http://www.numdam.org/article/RHM_2002__8_1_67_0.pdf.

Perhaps it is fair to say that most problems in Diophantus that lead to rational points on curves of genus $1$ are not given directly in Weierstrass form, but rather consist in making quartics $ax^4 + bx^2 + c$ equal to a square or in solving "double equations", i.e., making two at most quadratic
polynomials equal to a square simultaneously. For the equivalence to the modern formulation you may consult Weil's masterpiece on number theory from Hammurabi to Legendre.